# Next.js dynamic routes: avoid generating new pages for path params

Tags: javascript, next.js, ssg

**tl;dr: I need `mypage.com/users/123` to behave like `mypage.com/users?user_id=123`**

I'm using Next.js 10. I'd like to have routes like `mypage.com/users/123` and `mypage.com/users/445`. All my searches take me to dynamic routing, which suggests using this structure under the `pages` folder:

```
users/
   [user_id].js
```

This doesn't work for my case, because then a new page is generated in the server for every user. I only want one page, statically generated, under `users/`, that gets the `user_id` as a parameter on the client side.

With query params, this is straightforward. I can use this folder structure

```
users/
   index.js
```

and then, when someone goes to `mypage.com/users?user_id=123`, the **same** page gets served, and then client side js code can access the `user_id`.

#### Possible solution

My current solution (which I find too intricate, but may help someone) is adding a `rewrite` on `next.config.js`, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  rewrites() {
    return [{ source: '/users/:user_id', destination: '/users?user_id=:user_id' }];
  }
}
```